# Transforming burgers equation into the heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> We have Burgers equation
>
> $$ u_t - Du_{xx} - u u_x = 0$$
>
> We want to prove that we can transform this PDE into the heat equation
> $v_t = v_{xx}$ if we use $u = \phi_x$ where $\phi = - 2 D \ln v $.

## thoughts

Notice

$$ u_t = \frac{ \partial }{\partial x}  \phi_t = \left( - 2 D \frac{ v_t }{v} \right)_x $$

and our equation becomes

$$ \left( - 2 D \frac{ v_t }{v} \right)_x  = \left(  D u_x + \frac{u^2}{2}  \right)_x \implies - 2 D \frac{ v_t }{v} = D u_x + \frac{u^2}{2} +C(t)$$

where $C$ is any arbitrary function. Any ideas in how can we further simplify the above?